# nginx docker compose not up and running

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have below docker-compose for nginx service: however I don't see up and running for any service request to forward, is there something I'm doing wrong? any suggestion will be really helpful.

```
container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    command: >
      cat << EOF > /etc/nginx/conf.d/myproxy.conf
      server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/my.com.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/my.com.key;
        server_name my.app.com;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://service-name:443;
          }
        }
      EOF
      nginx -s reload;
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/my.com.key:/etc/nginx/my.com.key
      - ./nginx/my.com.cert:/etc/nginx/my.com.cert
    networks:
```

nginx should up and running, but I don't see any container running for Nginx.

---

### Solved:

I solved the issue by creating a custom conf file with all the server details and mapped that custom conf file to override existing conf and also, the deleted entrypoint and command block.

Comment: There might be a problem with `nginx -s reload` since nginx is not running at that moment. It should be visible in logs when you run `docker-compose up` (without `-d`). BTW you can save config in a file and mount it along with SSL cert and key. This way you won't have to hack into writing config at startup.

Comment: yes, I'm doing the mounting part it right now. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get rid of entire command and also entrypoint section! :).
write your nginx config in a file beside `docker-compose.yml` or where ever you want (lets name it `myproxy.conf`). Then, add `./myproxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/myproxy.conf` to valumes section.
Nginx docker images handles entrypoint it self and there is no need to interfere!

Your compose should be something like this:

```
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./myproxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/myproxy.conf
      - ./nginx/my.com.key:/etc/nginx/my.com.key
      - ./nginx/my.com.cert:/etc/nginx/my.com.cert
    networks:
```

Comment: Thanks, @mohammad Hosein I did exactly the same.